# Creating path variables from users list

Tags: list, powershell, import

Trying to generate a path according to a username list stored in a CSV file, this is the list of users:

- AAA
- AAB
- AAC
- AAD
- AAE
- AAF

This is my script:

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input path to Import CSV' 
$path = $path.Trim() 
$UserList=IMPORT-CSV $path 
ForEach ($name In $UserList){

$USERNAME =  $name 
$Drive_Home = "C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\" 
$Drive_Ams = Drive_Home+ "Amsterdam\" + $USERNAME
Write-output $Drive_Ams  }
```

This is the output:

> C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\Amsterdam@{Name=AAA}
> C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\Amsterdam@{Name=AAB}
> C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\Amsterdam@{Name=AAC}
> C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\Amsterdam@{Name=AAD}
> C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\Amsterdam@{Name=AAE}
> C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\Amsterdam@{Name=AAF}

My problem is to how to generate the path without `@{Name=`
for example, it should be `C:\Users\Local\Desktop\Home\Amsterdam\AAA`

Comment: @AdminOfThings that was easy :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must access the `Name` property to retrieve its value.

```
Foreach ($name in $UserList) {
    $Username = $name.Name
    # Other code
}
```

`Import-Csv` converts CSV file contents into custom objects. The properties of those objects are the column headers. If you specify the `-Header` parameter, you can provide an array of column headers. Otherwise, the first line of the file becomes the array of headers. Each header in the file must be separated by the provided delimiter (comma by default). Every other row of the CSV are objects with those headers as properties. The delimited data in each row becomes values of those properties.